# How to open terminal window and execute command in php?

Tags: java, php, linux, ubuntu, xampp

I am making a website which requires a java program to run on the server (it is a ubuntu server). I want to achieve this by executing it from php. I tried 'shell_exec' and 'exec', but they both don't open a terminal window or execute the jar file. It did work on my windows pc, but I want to have it work on my linux server as well. I am using xampp as server.

The command I used that worked on windows:

```
shell_exec("java -jar PATH/TO/JAR/FILE.jar PARAMETERS");
```

Comment: You can try `system()`, `passthru()` or `proc_open()`, I don't know how PHP works on Windows, maybe you will have to use different functions.

Comment: @BenoîtZu unfortunately, none of these functions work.

Comment: It doesn't actually open a visible terminal window but it should work.

Comment: Also make sure that the user that the php script is being executed as has access to the file and to execute it.

Comment: Also if the java app runs an async or long lived process you have to do some other stuff in your `shell_exec()` for it to keep running otherwise it runs and shuts right back down.

Comment: @Pitchinnate what kind of other stuff should I do then? Because it still only works on windows, not linux (and the terminal is indeed hidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself by adding '2>&1 &' at the end of the shell_exec() command. This makes the php script wait untill the program is finished.

The new command:

```
shell_exec("java -jar PATH/TO/JAR/FILE.jar PARAMETERS 2>&1 &");
```